# Weird memory leak with core data

Tags: iphone, core-data, memory-leaks, instruments

Instruments detect a memory leak:

```
(Leaked Object= "__NSCFString")
```

This is my code:

```
-(NSArray*)loadAllPages{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                                   entityForName:@"Page" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
                                        initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    myArray = [[NSArray alloc ]initWithArray:[[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]autorelease]];

    [fetchRequest release];
    if (myArray == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
    return myArray;
}
```

The line where leak is pointed at is initialization of `myArray`.
If I do not return `myArray`, this leak doesn't occur, so this is strange for me.

Comment: How do you call the method ? Do you use ARC ?

Comment: Where is `myArray` declared?

Comment: in my .h file. It doesn't matter if I declare it in the function or in .h, it just gives the same leak. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
myArray = [[NSArray alloc ]initWithArray:[[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]autorelease]];
```

the square brackets are slightly wrong. 
The `autorelease` is sent to the result of `[context executeFetchRequest:...]`, not to the allocated array.

`[context executeFetchRequest:...]` returns an autoreleased array. Sending `autorelease` to that array is an error. And `myArray` is allocated, but not released in your code.

The Xcode static analyzer also reports this as an error:

[image]

I assume that you meant

```
myArray = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]] autorelease];
```

which would result in an autoreleased array `myArray`.

Comment: No I did it intentionally. If I change to what you've suggested, it gives me a leak with details: Responsible Frame= "newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT" & Responsible Library= "CoreData"

Comment: @Sufian: But that looks to me like a different problem. I have updated my answer to make more clear why I think that your code has an error. - Have you tried the "Product -> Analyze" function in Xcode? That can often help to find retain/release problems.

Comment: Yes I did try Analyze feature but it is not pointing out anything as odd there. I m beginning to think this is because of returning the array. I even put the results in the other array (copying elements from the myArray) but same reason for leak.

Comment: @Sufian: That is strange, my Analyzer shows an error in your code. I have added a screenshot of the report to my answer.

Comment: I analyzed after making the changes you had suggested. I have some other functions using Core Data but none returns the array (of the fetched results) so maybe there is a problem returning the array? As I mentioned before, if I return nil, there is no error in Instruments.

Comment: @Sufian: Returning an array is no problem in general. What happens if you just use `NSArray *myArray = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]` ? If that doesn't help I am running out of ideas. I am quite sure that the `loadAllPages` is correct with my changes, so the problem is probably somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @Sufian: Did you make progress in this matter? Is there anything I can do to help?

Comment: No, not for now. Btw, thanks for the help. I will mark this as an answer as I personally think this is the only possible fix/upgrade on the initial code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ARC.

Change `return myArray;` with `return [myArray autorelease];`

You are returning an allocated object from your method, the ownership of that object is still with the method, in such scenarios you should return an auroreleased object and retain it on the receiving side. Then the ownership of that object will be with the calling method.

Comment: Now it gives me leaks with details:Responsible Frame= "newFetchedRowsForFetchPlan_MT" & Responsible Library= "CoreData". :-S